# MVC , IIS and Azure logging errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, log4net

I have an ASP.NET / MVC web site that can be deployed to

- IIS on premise
- IIS hosted by 3rd Party
- Azure WebSite

What is the best approach for logging so logs can be reviewed via azure but can still be reviewed via a log file.

I have used LOG4NET in the past for logging and its worked very well, wondering whats the best approach for Azure and if that approach works well for on premise.

My thinking is LOG4NET but configure it to log to Azure Diagnostics when hosted and just do some magic in the Web.Config when publishing to azure.

*EDIT*

I should have mentioned before, I don't want LOGS going out to the internet when the web is on premise, this makes application insights not usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think about trying ELMAh. It is a great tool for logging and I like it more than LOG4NET.
You could find a great guide using it with Azure at [using-elmah-in-windows-azure-web-sites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webapps/archive/2013/10/04/using-elmah-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx)

Comment: just installed with `Install-Package elmah` and its there, I can NAV to `/elmah.axd` and see the page, but if I do a simple test eg just throw an exception nothing gets logs. The docs suggest it will just pick up exception and log them. eg, override the default ASP / MVC stuff. Thanks -- I am reading the DOCS and FORUM BTW :)

Comment: the NU GET did not add `<modules *runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"*>`

Comment: yes thanks, not working quite right on azure but I will look at that later.